# Sum of column values in Pivot table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I have the table with the following details:

**Table**: ftest

```
create table ftest
(
  cola varchar(10),
  colb varchar(10)
)
```

**Insertion of records**:

```
insert into ftest values('A10','JK1');
insert into ftest values('A10','JK2');
insert into ftest values('A10','JK3');
insert into ftest values('A10','JK4');
insert into ftest values('A10','JK1');
```

**Pivot Table Script**:

```
select cola,JK1,JK2,JK3,JK4
from 
(
  select cola,colb 
  from ftest
)p
pivot
(
    count(colb)
    for colb in (JK1,JK2,JK3,JK4)
) as pvt;
```

**Getting Result**:

```
cola  JK1  JK2  JK3  JK4
------------------------
A10    2    1    1    1
```

**Expected Result**:

I want to sum the values of all columns `JK1,JK2,JK3,JK4` and assign it the the `SUM` column.

```
cola  JK1  JK2  JK3  JK4  SUM
-----------------------------
A10    2    1    1    1    5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few different ways that you can get a Total column.

You can add each of the columns together in the final select list:

```
select cola,JK1,JK2,JK3,JK4, 
  Total = JK1+JK2+JK3+JK4
from 
(
  select cola,colb
  from ftest
)p
pivot
(
  count(colb)
  for colb in (JK1,JK2,JK3,JK4)
) as pvt;
```

See [Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/251088/326916/pivot-with-total)

Or you can use a windowing function like `COUNT() OVER()` to get the total for each `cola` partition:

```
select cola,JK1,JK2,JK3,JK4, Total
from 
(
  select cola,colb,
    Total = count(*) over(partition by cola)
  from ftest
)p
pivot
(
  count(colb)
  for colb in (JK1,JK2,JK3,JK4)
) as pvt;
```

See [Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/251088/326819/pivot-with-total).  Both give a result of:

```
| COLA | JK1 | JK2 | JK3 | JK4 | TOTAL |
|------|-----|-----|-----|-----|-------|
|  A10 |   2 |   1 |   1 |   1 |     5 |
```